# URL config Wagtail-pages in own Django project

Tags: wagtail

I have set up my own Django-project. I have no own app’s installed. That’s for later. What I did was copying the ‘base’ and ‘blog’ app from the bakerydemo to my own project. These run fine, I can access the blog-pages and the admin-site from wagtail.
Only problem is the root url is now a blank-page (can’t add wagtail-field or anything). My wagtail homepage is now on ip-adress/home and it should be on ip-adress. This is my url-config:

```
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

path('cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
#    path('pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
path('', include(wagtail_urls)),

#    path("test404/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404.html")>
#    path("test500/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="500.html")>

]
```

How can I change this? So my first wagtail page is on root-url and not on root-url/home/

Thnx in advanced.

Edit: found this on the wagtail docs, but don’t know how to apply:

**Note that there’s one small difference when not using the Wagtail project template: Wagtail creates an initial homepage of the basic type Page, which does not include any content fields beyond the title. You’ll probably want to replace this with your own HomePage class - when you do so, ensure that you set up a site record (under Settings / Sites in the Wagtail admin) to point to the new homepage.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to move your wagtail page to root-url, you should create (or update) the default site so its root_page should be the page currently shown at /home/

[image: Screenshot of Wagtail admin toolbar showing where to find Sites item]

Comment: Hello CNK, thank you for the reply.
It helped me! Now the "homepage" is placed on my root-ip !

Comment: Only thing now is that in the menubar the root-url(homepage) is visible but there is also another "home"-menubutton which stands above the homepage url.
When i hover over that button the url is ip/None ?!

Comment: I see now the site-root has to be always in the menubar? :

>def get_site_root(context):
>   # This returns a core.Page. The main menu needs to have the site.root_page
>    # defined else will return an object attribute error ('str' object has no
>   # attribute 'get_children')
>  return Site.find_for_request(context["request"]).root_page

Comment: Solved it. A page was existing above my homepage.